# Get Dataset from a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dataset

how can i get the dataset from a gridview i have populated?

i tried this:

```
Dim importedDS As DataSet = gwResults.DataSource
```

but it's coming out blank all the time. is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find another way to store/retrieve/cache the dataset, or the specific values you need from it.

When you first retrieve a dataset and assign it to a Grid, you will be able to access it for the remainder of the page request. As soon as the page request is over, the HTTP context and page and any associated objects are purged, they will be set for garbage collection and destroyed. (As far as we're concerned, anyway)

On the next post back, the grid will reload it's values from the form, (and some properties from view state), but not the whole dataset, since that was never stored in the form/view state. Keeping a dataset in view state would be a incredibly inefficient. This is why the DataSource property will be blank on subsequent post backs.

Comment: If all you need is a specific value (or set of values) from a grid column, (such as an ID), you can you the grid view's DataKeys property. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

As another person mentioned, once the request is over - the objects aren't in scope anymore.
How are you binding the Grid to the DataSet and are you doing an if (!IsPostBack)?